# What is the good way to display the List of client name no - visit report in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have tried more and more way to display the no-visit report list but i failed. Well, The page must display the list of company that was not visit from the user choice's date picker.
Details: I have a table call

- Client table: ClientId, name, branch
- visit table: visitID, date, desc, ClientID_fk
- user : id, username, area

Now, each times that the user insert new visit record, there is a date, desc that he insert but the primary key and the foreign key are automatically load. **note:** *Client Branch =  User area*

**All I WANT IS to retrieve list of the client name that was not visit from a certain date. the data must not repeat twice . so I user Distinct** 
Like e.g: output must be : Chris 2014-02-01 not visited yet.

***This is my non visit SQL Query code***:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  cl.Name
FROM
    Visits_table vt
        LEFT JOIN
    Client_table cl ON (cl.Client_Id = vt.client_fk)
        STRAIGHT_JOIN
    user u ON (u.area = vt.Branch)

WHERE
    cl.Branch = vt.Branch
        AND u.username = 'Anthony'
        AND vt.Start_Date <= '2014-10-12'

ORDER BY cl.Name ASC ;
```

Comment: [Elie](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3963097/elie-mbuyamba) you just want to formate the data obtained from query like this---Chris 2014-02-01 not visited yet. is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is something like the following:

```
SELECT
    cl.Name,
    max(vt.Start_Date) LastVisit
FROM
    Client_table cl
LEFT JOIN
    Visits_table vt on (cl.Client_Id = vt.client_fk)
JOIN
    user u on (u.area = vt.Branch)
WHERE
    u.username = 'Anthony'
GROUP BY
    cl.Name
HAVING
    LastVisit is null or
    LastVisit <= '2014-10-12'
ORDER BY
    cl.Name
```

Comment: Thank you @phylogenesis! That's also a good subjection answer.

Answer (score 0):

Guys Thanks for you Answers.
This is what I found:

And it's working.

Thank you Phylo As well

$result = mysql_query("Select username, Name, Suburb from Client_table, user

WHERE

Client_Id NOT IN 
(SELECT Distinct client_fk AS callesmade FROM Visits_table
WHERE Start_Date >= '".$Fdate."')

AND

Branch = area

AND

Branch = area

ORDER BY username, Name ASC");